# VT vs RVT capacitors: what do they mean?

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics

I see on these two products, which have the same function (and obviously also the same construction; these are switches which allow activating/deactivating individually the power supplies of one or more hard disks in a computer), that some use "100 16V VT" capacitors and others use "100 16V RVT" capacitors:

[Chenyang PW-020-CY](https://www.amazon.fr/chenyang-Syst%C3%A8me-contr%C3%B4le-Intelligent-Disque/dp/B0816F5HX4)

[KSTE HL1031-N230](https://www.amazon.fr/KSTE-Commutateur-S%C3%A9lecteur-Switcher-Ordinateur/dp/B082D7GY6J)

I didn't find an explanation anywhere for the differences between the VT versus RVT markings.

Could you clarify the meaning of these two acronyms to me, and above all, their differences?

Comment: You would have to know the capacitor manufacturer first to know what the code means. Most likely it is a lot code, date code, or plant code so most likely neither capacitor is better.

Comment: Anyone wishing to know the difference needs more than an amazon link to make a comparison. Amazon links are completely unreliable in terms of the information they give. Data sheets (on the other hand) are a much more reliable source. If there are no data sheets for either, then nobody can answer this.

Comment: @Andyaka:Sorry, but this is the only thing I have. More, these Amazon links ARE reliable to see the marking on the capacitors. And even without link, explaining what a marking on a capacior means "should" be possible.

Comment: @Justme: Hmmm... I suppose you're wrong, don't you ? Doesn't these means 220 uF, 16V, and... someting I don't know ? Because RVT seems to have some signification in the capacitors world : http://www.elna.co.jp/en/capacitor/alumi/catalog/pdf/rvt_e_p80-81.pdf, https://www.xuanxcapacitors.com/capacitors/rvt-smd-aluminum-electrolytic-capacitor-100uf6-3v But I may be wrong

Comment: @Oliver Nobody is wrong here. Elna does have a RVT series of capacitors, but if you look at the datasheet you posted, the capacitors do not read RVT anywhere, and they include Elna specific date code. As the manufacturer of caps in your photos is unknown, the markings remain unknown.

Comment: @Justme:You will note that Elna mention RVK and RVT at the top of the document. So I guess these 2 acronyms have a meaning, as well as VT. Hence my question.

Comment: @Justme:Doesn't these markings means 220 uF, 16V, and... an acronym that may have a meaning in the electronic world ?

Comment: It is already been mentioned that these markings depend on the capacitor manufacturer. It can be a lot code or manufacturing date code, but to decipher that you need to know the manufacturer to decode what it means. So yes, it means something to the manufacturer. To us, we cannot answer you what it means.

Comment: @Justme:OK, so just to be clear, capacitors doesn't have any standard markings as other components can have (ex : resistors), is that what I have to understand ?

Comment: Capacitors usually have capacitance and voltage printed in a way that is understood by humans, but not always, as even those can be printed in manufacturer specific codes. The rest is really manufacturer specific markings, and what they mean may or may not be known from manufacturer documentation. There are no standards to what these codes mean.

Answer (score 4):

VT is used as a series moniker for (Chinese) [unbranded](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811051716_VT-Vertical-Technology-VT1C681M-CRG10_C305384.pdf) and also for branded ([Multicomp Pro](http://www.multicomp-pro.com/)) capacitors.

RVT is a series of capacitors made by [Elna](http://www.elna.co.jp/en/capacitor/alumi/catalog/pdf/rvt_e_p80-81.pdf), but it is also the marking of a series of wide-temperature capacitors by [Xuanx](https://www.xuanxcapacitors.com/), and quite probably others.

Both VT and RVT are names of *series* of capacitors (capacitors with different values but similar specifications, usually made by a single manufacturer), but the actual meaning of the names and markings (and the specs of the capacitors) will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer.

The markings by themselves tell you little or nothing; they will only make sense when you know the manufacturer, so you can look up the appropriate datasheets.

Comment: @Justme:do these have something to do with this question ? https://www.edaboard.com/threads/hvt-lvt-and-rvt-cells-what-is-rvt.276647/ and https://www.edaboard.com/threads/what-is-meant-by-hvt-svt-cells-in-library.101239/